# X11 on Ubuntu, all characters missing, while working fine with Xming on Windows

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, xorg, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to access a server with GUI through X11 on a PC with Ubuntu. The forwarding seems good, just with all characters missing:
[screenshot_ubuntu_X11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JaP4.png)

However, I also tried to use PuTTY and Xming on Win10 to connect the same server, and everything works fine:
[screenshot_win10_Xming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNxxq.png)

I thought it could be a font issue. But I tried to install several xfont packages and it doesn't help. I also tried this: https://github.com/zub2/xfonts-ucs

What the actual problem could be and how to fix it?

Thanks to all reading this!